# How to setup a deeply nested form in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I'm trying to build a rather complex nested form in rails and am stuck.

Basically, I have three models - `Applicant`, `DataPoint`, `ApplicantDataPointValue` .

The user can create a new `DataPoint`, give it a name ("gender" etc.) select it's type ("string","integer" etc.). The type determines what column the data will eventually be saved in in the `ApplicantDataPointValue` table.

I then want the user, when they're creating a new `Applicant`, to be able to add a value for each `DataPoint` into the `ApplicantDataPointValue` table

My models look like the following:

Applicant:

```
class Applicant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :applicant_data_point_values, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :data_points, :through => :applicant_data_point_values

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :data_points
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :applicant_data_point_values

  attr_accessible :data_points_attributes, :applicant_data_point_values_attributes
end
```

DataPoint:

```
class DataPoint < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :applicant_data_point_values
  has_many :applicants, :through => :applicant_data_point_values
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :applicant_data_point_values
end
```

ApplicantDataPointValue:

```
class ApplicantDataPointValue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :data_point
  belongs_to :applicant
end
```

But I'm at a loss to what to do in the 'new' and 'create' sections of my controller or how to construct the form.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, the form for the User will also have multiple ApplicantDataPointValue fields. (but that form won't allow creating of new DataPoint fields, right?)

In the controller `new` action, you'll want to set up your model with associated data point values:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  DataPoint.all.each do |data_point|
    applicant_data_point_value = @user.applicant_data_point_values.build
    applicant_data_point_value.data_point = data_point
  end
end
```

And then, display a text box for each data point value.

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <% @user.applicant_data_point_values.each do |data_point_value| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :applicant_data_point_values, data_point_value do |fields| %>

    <%= fields.label :value, data_point_value.data_point.type %>
    <%= fields.text_field :value %>

  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Reference: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Comment: Fiona, thanks. That seems to be heading in the right direction. However, I need to save the results into their correct columns (string, integer etc.) in the ApplicantDataPointValues table so have to include a bunch of IF statements into my form that, depending on the data_point.type, renders the correct field_text etc. for them.

However, when I click save the form doesn't save and I get a `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'data_point_type' for nil:NilClass)` for the first IF. Any ideas?:

`<% if data_point_value.data_point.data_point_type == "string" %>`

Comment: I.E. Do I need to add something to the #Create section of my controller as well?

Comment: OR should I handle the decision of what column to save the value in in the ApplicantDataPointValue column?

Comment: Can you show me your `create` method? It should only try to re-render the form if the model's`save` fails, and that's a separate kettle of fish. Check out http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised.

Comment: `  def create
    @applicant = Applicant.new(params[:applicant])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @applicant.save
        format.html { redirect_to @applicant, notice: 'Applicant was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @applicant, status: :created, location: @applicant }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @applicant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end`

Comment: I figured out what the problem was. I had a validation on the `ApplicantDataPointValue` model that it must include the `DataPoint` ID that's why it was failing in the submission of the form.

Any ideas on how I can pass the 'data_point' ID through the form as well as the 'applicant' ID (I know I can do it with a hidden_field in the form but that just doesn't feel the most elegant way...)